# Python Selenium - AttributeError : WebElement object has no attribute sendKeys in textarea

Tags: python, selenium, attributes, sendkeys

My code :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
driver=webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.58yumi.com/")
driver.find_element_by_id("UserName").send_keys("XXXXXXX")
driver.find_element_by_id("Password").send_keys( "XXXXXX")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(@type,'submit')]").click()
driver.get("http://www.58yumi.com/user_jiexi.htm")
driver.find_element_by_id("cznr").sendKeys("XXXX.com|forcname|CNAME|forcname.XXXX.com.a.bdydns.com|default");
......
```

I get error in element_by_id("cznr") :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'sendKeys'
```

html :

```
<textarea id="cznr" onkeyup="czhang();" name="ymlb" cols="60" class="inputs2" rows="10"></textarea>
```

Help ....
How to input data in textarea ?

Comment: Sorry change Question ....

Comment: Please don't edit the question based on which you have received well researched answers. Once you receive canonical answers changing the question can make all the answers invalid and may not be useful to future readers. If your requirement have changed feel free to raise a new question. StackOverflow contributors will be happy to help you out. For the time being I have reverted back the question to it's initial state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `sendKeys()` which is *Java* based method with *Python* based method **`send_keys()`** in the line:

```
driver.find_element_by_id("cznr").sendKeys("XXXX.com|forcname|CNAME|forcname.XXXX.com.a.bdydns.com|default");
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong function name -- `sendKeys` vs. `send_keys`.

You must have copied that line from a Java sample program, which does use `sendKeys` as the function name.